# Find the maximum value of x in terms of n given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

> If $(5n!)^n$ is divisible by $5^x$, find the maximum value of $x$ in terms of $n$.

My Approach:

I have solved this problem like this

For example let say to calculate number of fives in $10$! will be $\frac{10}{5}=2$.

Number of fives in $25!$ will be $\frac{25}{5}+\frac{25}{25}=6...$

So for $n=1,2,3,...$

Number of fives will be... $1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12...$ and so on..

Now, there is one thing to note that $20!$ will have $4$ fives, but $25!$

will have $6$ fives. Similarly, $45!$ will have $10$ fives but $50!$ will have

$12$ fives.

So the series will be like
(1+2+3.... )-(5+11+17...) whose sum will be

$n\frac{n+1}{2}-(5+(n-1)6)$

After solving this I will get the value of $n$.

> Am I right in my approach?Please correct me if I am wrong.
>
> I am also confused about Have I used (5n!) right

Comment: Why there are negative votes?Can anyone explain me clearly?

Comment: You have 52 questions on this site but cannot put the question in Latex/MathJax format.

Comment: I tried to reformat the post as best as possible. For next time: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x$. When $p$ is prime, and $p^{v_p(n!)}$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n!$,we have $$v_p(n!)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[n p^{-j}].$$ Only finitely many terms in the above summation are non-zero because $[n p^{-j}]=0$ when $p^j>n$. The first term in the summation counts $1$ for each $k>0$ such that $p k\leq n$.The second term counts $1$ more for each $k$ such that $p^2 k\leq n$.The third term......(guess)..............Of course the largest power of $5$ that divides $(5 n)!^n$ is $n. v_5(5n).$